# Angular momentum, decay

Tags: particle-physics, angular-momentum, quantum-spin

A dumb question:

When we do tensor products on angular momentum quantum numbers, for example in a decay:
\begin{equation}
A \rightarrow B+C+D
\end{equation}

Then
\begin{equation}
J(A) = J(B+C+D) = J(B) \otimes J(C) \otimes J(D) 
\end{equation}

Where are we accounting of the possible angular momentum **between** the decay products?

We have just accounted of their intrinsic angular momentum.

Comment: Yes, you account for the relative orbital momenta separately. Typically, you combine B&C first, adding their spins to their relative orbital L, and then the answer(s) to D, involving *their* relative orbital L...  Your textbook presumably covers several examples of this...

Comment: I don't have a textbook, so it does not cover several examples of this

Comment: Can you give me a chapter book reference?

Comment: No, not really... Might read up on [this?](https://halldweb.jlab.org/DocDB/0033/003345/002/dalitz.pdf)...